# android app crashing on start-up

Tags: android

I am new to android . I am troubling during 2 weeks with an simple android apps which I am developing. In my app , I am trying to fetch a simple text from php . But every time when I try to launch the app it crashed.  My code is below

```
package com.example.test;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://logger.net46.net/android/hello.php");
    try {
       HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
       final String str =  EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
       TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
       tv.setText(str);
    } 
   catch (IOException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
    }



}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

I can not finding out where is my problem. Please someone help me.

Comment: you can't connect to internet in main Thread, use `AsyncTask` class to get data from internet

Comment: Learn how to read logcat.  The stack trace in logcat tells you exactly what the problem is and where it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably getting `NetWorkOnMainThreadException`. You should use a `Thread` or `AsyncTask` for making the http post request and update ui on the ui thread.

Example:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView tv; 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        new TheTask().execute();
    }
      class TheTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>
      {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String str = null;
            try
            {
              HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
              HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://logger.net46.net/android/hello.php");
              HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
              str =  EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());     
            } 
            catch (IOException e) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                   e.printStackTrace();
                }

            return str;

      }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            tv.setText(result);
        }

      }
}
```

Snap

[image]

Comment: thanks for your reply.I have tried your code. But unfortunately my data is not loading from php file. Could you please solve this problem?

Comment: @MushfiqulTuhin use HttpGet instead of HttpPost. you are not posting anything and make sure you added internet permission in manifest

Comment: @MushfiqulTuhin fortunately the same code and the same url works for me. see the snap. make sure you added internet permission and also make sure the id referenced for textview from xml matches

Comment: Its not still working with me. For testing purpose I have added this code on onPostExecute() method. 
"tv.setText("debugging");" . But it does not show the text. So I think this method is not calling. Am I right? what should I do now.

note: I have also added internet permission in manifest.xml file.

Comment: @MushfiqulTuhin it will work AFAIK if you use the code in my post. If not you are doing it wrong. Post the whole updated code

Comment: It works, I had a problem with my wifi. So internet connection was turned off. Thank you very much for help me.